# Parse open source server cloud code not working the same as old

Tags: android, ios, node.js, parse-server

I went from using the old parse cloud code to open source parse server on AWS and this part of the `main.js` does not work.

```
    var Stripe = require('stripe');
    Stripe.initialize('sk_live_mylivekey');

    var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
    Mailgun.initialize("mydomain.mailgun.org");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native Cloud code modules like Stripe, Mailgun, Sendgrid, Twilio etc. are not available in the open sourced Parse server.

Use official npm modules for the same:

1. [Stripe npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stripe)
2. [Mailgun npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js)

Reference: [Migrate an existing Parse app - Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App#3-cloud-code)

Note:

> Because the Parse hosted Cloud Code isn’t running a full node environment, there may be subtle differences in how your Cloud Code runs in Parse Server. We recommend exercising all your critical code paths to ensure full functionality.

Comment: I am still having problems with creating a Parse.Object but the server runs and does not crash

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using cloud code for making charges to creating a route in my index.js file for making charges. In index.js create a route as such

```
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_****');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.post('/charge', function(req, res){
    var token = req.body.token;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    stripe.charges.create({
        amount: amount,
        currency: 'usd',
        source: token,
    }, function(err, charge){
        if(err)
            // Error check
        else
            res.send('Payment successful!');
    }
});
```

I call this route using jQuery post however, you could also call it in a form

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_****',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token){
        $.post('/charge', {
            token: token.id,
            amount: total,
        }, function(data, status){
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```